# BufferedReader While Reading Json Data

Tags: java, android, json, bufferedreader

Why do we add `\n` while reading `JSON` data with a `BufferedReader`?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Comment: No.. Your app don't crash if you don't add `\n`. We add `\n` because `reader.readLine()` receive the data up to new line("\n").

Comment: No Its Not Crashing...

Comment: It's used just to have the same output formats (as input). It prevent from having only one line in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not *adding* a `\n` - you're putting a line break back which `readLine()` effectively swallowed. For example, if your text file initially consists of 5 lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

then `reader.readLine()` will return (in successive calls) `"line1"`, `"line2"`, `"line3"`, `"line4"`, `"line5"`... without the line ending at which `BufferedReader` detected the end of the line.

So if you just had `sb.append(line)`, you'd end up with a `StringBuilder` containing:

```
line1line2line3line4line5
```

Having said that, the code seems *somewhat* pointless - it's really just normalizing the line breaks. Unless you actually need that, you might as well just use call `read` instead of `readLine()` and copy the text that way...

Comment: `line1 line2 line3 line4 line5`???? You mean `"line1\nline2\nline3\nline4\nline5\n"`?

Comment: @greenapps: No, I mean what I've written. Because `line` won't contain the line-break, because `BufferedReader.readLine()` doesn't include it. Note the lack of spaces in what I've written, too...

Comment: Well the point of my comment was to first show exactly the text that was sent and than  the result if the removed linebreaks are not added again. I was missing that in your explanation.

Comment: @greenapps: Ah, you were referring to the initial scenario part of "if your text file initially consists of 5 lines", right? There were line-breaks in the markdown, but I hadn't added enough indentation - fixed now.

Comment: It makes more sense now. But you did not show the `\n`'s. And the point that `"line1\nline2\nline3\nline4\nline5\n"` converts to `"line1line2line3line4line5"`.if the \n is not added again.

Comment: @greenapps: Not sure what you mean by "you did not show the `\n`s". It's implicit that there *are* line breaks (which may or may not be `\n`) when the file looks like it does. It's not clear whether you're still suggesting there's something wrong with the answer...

Comment: The linebreaks are implicit. What i was suggesting is that explicit mentioning would help understand the issue. The answer is not wrong but could benefit from my comments i think.

Comment: @greenapps: It certainly benefited from you pointing out that I had messed up the formatting, but I think at that point there's no need for more detail - saying that there are 5 lines and then showing 5 lines gives enough information...